# Getting the coordinates of the object

Tags: three.js, coordinates, autodesk-forge

I am new in forge. How we can get the coordinates or the threejs Vector of the object by its ID like "getBoundingBox"? e.g. I want to get the coordinates of the wall of the house.

Comment: Could you please share more information, code, and an example or details of what you are exactly trying to do? We cannot help with the information provided.

Comment: I want to launch an app, which should set automatically sensors on the 3D-model of the house. My site [link](http://autodesk8.vuztc.ru) has an example (simple room). I need to know how it is possible to get the coordinates of the ceiling in order to know where I should place the sensors using three.js. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mesh.geometry 
Geometry.computeBoundingBox()
Geometry.center()
```

Hope helpful.

Comment: I can't understand how to use it. I have a forge id (4028). How can I get its coordinates? If possible give a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

[This sample code](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/getting-bounding-boxes-of-each-component-in-the-viewer.html) shows how to draw a bounding box around an element. The coordinate of an element may vary according to the inser or reference point that you consider for each one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need in your case is getting coordinates on the vertices rather than the bounding box, which may be quite approximative in some cases. Take a look at this article for pointers on how to get started:

[Accessing mesh information with the Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/accessing-mesh-information-with-the-view-data-api.html)